# On DetailViewController,countdown

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have a countdown timer it working in cell. I’m pushing cell and shown DetailView Controller. On DetailViewController, countdown not working.
For example, in cell my countdown shown look like | 23 days 14 hours 45 min 33 sec | and working. I’m pushing cell and on DetailViewController shown label like  | 23 days 14 hours 45 min 32 sec |   but not working.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.label.text = self.tweetMessage;
    self.username.text = self.userId;
    self.count.text = self.countdownStartTime;

    NSTimer *timer;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(updateTime)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}

-(void)updateTime
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSUInteger preservedComponents = (NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay);
    self.datePicker.date = [calendar dateFromComponents:[calendar components:preservedComponents fromDate:self.datePicker.date]];

    //Get the time left until the specified date
    NSInteger ti = ((NSInteger)[self.datePicker.date timeIntervalSinceNow]);
    NSInteger seconds = ti % 60;
    NSInteger minutes = (ti / 60) % 60;
    NSInteger hours = (ti / 3600) % 24;
    NSInteger days = (ti / 86400);

    //Update the lable with the remaining time
    self.count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02li days %02li hours %02li min %02li sec", (long)days, (long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Continue"]){
        DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.tweetMessage = ((TWTTweetTableViewCell *)sender).tweetMessage.text;
        controller.userId = ((TWTTweetTableViewCell *)sender).user.text;
        controller.countdownStartTime = ((TWTTweetTableViewCell *)sender).countdownTime.text;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the code from the `MainViewController` or the `DetailViewController`?

Comment: Can you post the code where you push the `DetailViewController`?

Comment: I'm pushing my cell.and goes to DetailViewController

Comment: this code from detailViewContoller.

Comment: countdown label shown but not working. nastimer or nsdate method not working i think.

Comment: Have you tried debugging and find out if the method `updateTime` is actually being called every second?

Comment: Yes.. But not working.

Comment: Does it work if you change your method signature to be `-(void)updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer`

Comment: I have created a small sample project and it looks the timer works: https://github.com/pgpbpadilla/objc-exercises/blob/master/NSTimerTest/DetailViewController.m#L40 Can you check it out and compare?

Comment: When i add this code "(NSTimer *)timer" method definition for "updateTime" not found error.

Comment: @pgpb.padilla i add ":(NSTimer *)timer" but yellow error.how can i fix it?

Comment: @pgpb.padilla Our project wery similar, your working. mine not working with same code :)

Comment: @pgpb.padilla can you help me please ?

Comment: I reviewed your code, are you passing the `NSDate` object to your `DetailViewController`? Make sure that you do `[destinationViewController setDetailItem: date]` on the `prepareForSegue` method of the `MainViewController`. If you don't then `[_detailItem timeIntervalSinceNow]` will not have the right value.

Comment: @pgpb.padilla Thanks for your Answer. This is my segue method how can i change ? i add prepareForSegue method.

Comment: Anybody help me please ?

Comment: Change `NSInteger ti = ((NSInteger)[self.datePicker.date timeIntervalSinceNow]);` to `NSInteger ti = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceNow];` and let me know what happens.

Comment: I changed my Friend.But not running countdown label. shown like 00 days 00 hours 00 min 00 sec.

Comment: not running countdown label. shown like 32 days 45 hours 21 min 12 sec and then after 1 sec shown like 00 days 00 hours 00 min 00 sec.

Comment: @pgpb.padilla i thing segue problem.

Comment: Create a property `NSDate* myDate`, then in `viewDidLoad` initialize it to `myDate = [NSDate date];` then change `NSInteger ti = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceNow]` to `NSInteger ti = [myDate timeIntervalSinceNow];` and try again

Comment: @pgpb.padilla no running My Friend..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  self.label.text = self.tweetMessage;
  self.username.text = self.userId;
  self.count.text = self.countdownStartTime;

  NSTimer *timer;
  timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                           target:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateTime)
                                         userInfo:nil
                                          repeats:YES];
  }

-(void)updateTime
{

```
//Get the time left until the specified date
NSInteger ti = ((NSInteger)[self.datePicker.date timeIntervalSinceNow]);
NSInteger seconds = ti % 60;
NSInteger minutes = (ti / 60) % 60;
NSInteger hours = (ti / 3600) % 24;
NSInteger days = (ti / 86400);

//Update the lable with the remaining time
self.countdownTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02li days %02li hours %02li min %02li sec", (long)days, (long)hours, (long)minutes, (long)seconds];
```

}

```
enter code here
```

Not working my Friend..

Comment: In DetailViewController, i should have a NSDate object that holds the countdown start time (in addition to the NSString) and i should use that in my update time method instead of the datePicker's date, which is always nil.But how ?